# SQL 2008 CASE statement aggravation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why does this fail:

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(50) = 'dasf'
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(@DATE) = 1 THEN CONVERT(date,@DATE) ELSE @DATE END
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date
>   and/or time from character string.

Why is it trying to convert dasf to date when it clearly causes ISDATE(@DATE) = 1 to evaluate to false...

If I do:

```
SELECT ISDATE(@DATE)
```

The return value is 0.

Comment: A column can only be one data type - it's either DATE, or VARCHAR(50).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CASE returns a single type.  In this case, the type is Date, found from your THEN clause.  It is implicitly converting the ELSE clause result to Date to match.

You must choose a single type to be returned by CASE.  It cannot be used to return sometimes Date and sometimes varchar.

from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

> Return Types
>
> Returns the highest
>   precedence type from the set of types
>   in result_expressions and the optional
>   else_result_expression. For more
>   information, see Data Type Precedence
>   (Transact-SQL).

and then following that link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

> 8) date
>
> 27) varchar

---

It's not clear what you want, so it's hard to offer alternatives (I don't know if the CASE is part of a larger query or script), but here's a couple things you can do:

```
-- choose a single return type per CASE expression
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN IsDate(@Date) = 1
    THEN convert(date, @Date)
    ELSE null
  END as [Date],
  CASE
    WHEN IsDate(@Date) = 1
    THEN null
    ELSE @Date
  END as [VarChar]

--use control flow to select what you want.
IF IsDate(@Date) = 1
THEN
  SELECT convert(date, @Date)
ELSE
  SELECT @Date
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there some alternate way to do what I need?

Comment: What do you want to do, if it is not a date do you want to actually return a non-date value?  What is the meaning of the resulting column.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(50) = 'dasf'
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN ISDATE(@DATE)=1 THEN CONVERT(char(23),CONVERT(date,@DATE),121) 
           ELSE @DATE
       END
```

It will basically format your valid date and leave the non-dates alone. Is that what you are after?

actual working sample:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (DATE VARCHAR(50))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('dasf')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('1/1/2010')

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ISDATE(DATE)=1 THEN CONVERT(char(23),CONVERT(datetime,DATE),121) 
        ELSE DATE
    END AS DATE
    FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
DATE
--------------------------------------------------
dasf
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

In the working example, I made a substitute from `date` data type to `datetime` because I'm on SQL Server 2005 and `date` datatype is SQL Server 2008 only.

Comment: Thanks, this example allowed me to formulate a way to do exactly what I needed...